# How do I get this for loop to create one dataframe, instead of creating a new one each time it loops?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

So, I am trying to return a dataframe of the values that are separated by a - or a / in my original dataframe. It does this, however seems to create a new df every time and I can't concatenate them either?

```
lst = []
for item in ref100.Class:
    if len(item) > 3:
        result = re.sub("[^0-9]", " ", item)
        lst1 = result.split(' ')
        lst = pd.DataFrame(lst1)
        lst.replace('', np.nan, inplace = True)
        lst.dropna(inplace = True)
        print (lst)
```

which returns:

```
    0
1  43
2  44
    0
1  45
2  47
```

but I want

```
    0
1  43
2  44
3  45
4  47
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "It does this, however seems to create a new df every time" Yes, because that's what `lst = pd.DataFrame(lst1)` means. "and I can't concatenate them either?" Well, how did you try? Do you know how to concatenate DataFrames in general? If not, did you try using a search engine to look for a way? (You already know the word "concatenate", so you should definitely be educated enough to figure this part out.) If you do know, what happened when you tried writing code with that approach?

Comment: use iloc to update your row in the dataframe. use a regular expression to substitute for a pattern in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider generalizing your process in a defined method. Then build a list of data frames to be concatenate together at the end:

```py
def build_frame(item):
    result = re.sub("[^0-9]", " ", item) 
    lst1 = result.split(' ') 
    df = pd.DataFrame(lst1).replace('', np.nan).dropna()
    
    return df
    
final_df = pd.concat(
     [build_frame(item) for item in ref100["Class"] if len(item) > 3]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - worked perfectly! I am currently working on further "generalizing" my coding so this helps tremendously.